# How to properly link gfortran and gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write a C function that calls a piece of fortran code.  I thought it would be easier to try to link the fortran code directly versus trying to rewrite the fortran into C.  I am using gcc/g++/gfortran on a mac where I directly downloaded the binaries and installed them.

The fortran code is at https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vmod/igrf12.f.  The specific subroutine I want to call is `subroutine igrf12syn (isv,date,itype,alt,colat,elong,x,y,z,f)`

The wrapper I wrote is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
 double *colat, double *elong, double* x,double* y, double* z, double* f );

int main(){
    double B[4], BabsDervs[3], BrDervs[3], BthDervs[3], BphDervs[3];
    double r, th, ph,year,alt2,lat,colat,elong,x,y,z,f;
    int isv;

    // igrf12syn (isv,date,itype,alt,colat,elong,x,y,z,f)
    r = 6371e3;
    th = 0.57;
    ph = 0;

    year = 2015;
    alt2 = 200.0;
    lat = 33.25;
    colat = 90.0-lat;
    elong = 0.0;
    isv =1;
    igrf12syn_(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);

    printf("%0.4e",f);
 return 0;
 }
```

The commands I am using to compile and call this are:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc -lgfortran -c testigrf.c igrf12.f
/usr/local/bin/gcc -lgfortran -o b.out testigrf.o igrf12.o
```

The error I get is:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
testigrf.o
igrf12.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [igrf] Error 1
```

I understand what this error means and I can produce the `nm` files for the `.o` files which shows both of the `main` functions.  However, I am not sure how to change the Fortran code to get rid of this error.

So my questions are the following:
1. How do I change the Fortran or C code to fix this issue? Particularly, since the fortran code starts with `PROGRAM IGRF`

2. Am I calling the `igrf12syn` routine properly?  I am worried I am not calling it correctly.  I may also be doing a poor job passing in the variables, which has to be done by reference.

Thanks for help, and please let me know if I am doing something really silly in calling the routines.

Comment: There is no language C/C++, only the two **different** languages C and C++! Your code looks like C.

Comment: An do not post links. A question must be self-contained. Also note your question contains off-topic questions, is too broad and lacks information. Read [ask].

Comment: the link was posted since I do not think it is worthwhile to copy all of that code into this post.  The `igrf12.f` is in the public domain.  Will edit out question 3.

Comment: Also, I understand that C and C++ are two different languages.  But you can compile C code using g++ and proper headers.

Comment: No, you cannot. You can use a common subset, which is smaller than you think. However told you different does not know at least of of them well enought to write much more than "Hello world". Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: And avoiding too long code is why we ask for a [mcve] - mind the first word.

Comment: Your fortran code is an entire `PROGRAM`. Just keep the `SUBROUTINE`-s there.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for pointing that out, it is useful information for the future.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your C program `testigrf.c` is defective. As it is,
you have the warning:

```
testigrf.c: In function ‘main’:
testigrf.c:23:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘igrf12syn_’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     igrf12syn_(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
     ^
```

which occurs because your have declared a function called `igrf12syn` and invoked
one called `igrf12syn_`, about which the compiler knows nothing.

Change `igrf12syn_` to `igrf12syn`, recompile, and then the errors revealed are:

```
testigrf.c: In function ‘main’:
testigrf.c:23:26: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘igrf12syn’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
                          ^
testigrf.c:3:14: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
  extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
              ^
testigrf.c:23:44: error: incompatible type for argument 7 of ‘igrf12syn’
     igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
                                            ^
testigrf.c:3:14: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
  extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
              ^
testigrf.c:23:46: error: incompatible type for argument 8 of ‘igrf12syn’
     igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
                                              ^
testigrf.c:3:14: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
  extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
              ^
testigrf.c:23:48: error: incompatible type for argument 9 of ‘igrf12syn’
     igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
                                                ^
testigrf.c:3:14: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
  extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
              ^
testigrf.c:23:50: error: incompatible type for argument 10 of ‘igrf12syn’
     igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
                                                  ^
testigrf.c:3:14: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
  extern void igrf12syn( int *isv, double *year, double *itype, double *alt,
              ^
```

Read the diagnostics and fix the errors before you go any further. They
might be fixed, for example, by changing:

```
double r, th, ph,year,alt2,lat,colat,elong,x,y,z,f;
```

to

```
double r, th, ph,year,alt2,lat,colat,elong,x,y,z,f,itype;
```

and changing:

```
igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&isv,&r, &th, &ph,x,y,z,f);
```

to:

```
igrf12syn(&isv,&year,&itype,&r, &th, &ph,&x,&y,&z,&f);
```

That will satisfy the compiler, though it may not express your intentions,
which are not clear to me.

You understand that you cannot link two *programs* into a single program,
since the linker will find duplicate `main` functions. You need to link
the C main program just with the Fortran subroutine `igrf12syn`.

Next, download and save the file `https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vmod/igrf12.f`.
Open it in a text/programming editor. Select all the of lines - the complete
lines, including leading space - that compose the subroutine `igrf12syn`, from:

```
  subroutine igrf12syn (isv,date,itype,alt,colat,elong,x,y,z,f)
```

to:

```
 end
```

Save this selection exactly as copied in a new file `igrf12syn.f` in the
same directory as `testigrf.c`.

Then, open a console in that directory and execute the following commands:

```
$ gcc -c -o testigrf.o testigrf.c
$ gfortran -fno-underscoring -c -o igrf12syn.o igrf12syn.f
$ gfortran -o testigrf testigrf.o igrf12syn.o
```

These will compile and link your program as `testigrf` in the same directory.

Finally, repeat the first two commands, each with the additional option `-Wall`,
to see the warnings that you are not yet aware of. Consider fixing the program
to remove the warnings, as they may well mean that the program will not
behave as you expect. Always include `-Wall` in your `gcc/g++/gfortran` compiler
options when compiling code of any importance to you.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this answer is basically correct.  I should have thought and worked a little harder before posting.  I will note, I used the following for the shell commands and it worked: `gcc -lgfortran -c testigrf.c igrf12syn.f` and 
 `gcc  -lgfortran -o b.out testigrf.o igrf12syn.o`
 ./b.out

Comment: @AD0AE Good. However neither of the commands `gcc -lgfortran -c testigrf.c igrf12syn.f`nor `gcc -lgfortran -o b.out testigrf.o igrf12syn.o` makes good sense. (I'm assuming `./b.out`
has a newline). The 1st ignores linkage option `-lgfortran` because `-c` means "compile only, don't link". The 2nd ignores `-lgfortran` because it precedes the object files in the linkage sequence.  For me, the result is undefined reference linkage errors for the symbols referenced in `libgfortran` and `libm`, which is as it should be. If you use a very old GCC (pre 4.7 I think) then your linkage would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I called Fortran routines, but your work looks plausible.

Now write a short fortran subroutine which you compile in an independant file, testing your call by reference subroutine parameters.

```
      subroutine igrf12syn (isv,date,itype,alt,colat,elong,x,y,z,f)
```

Of course you might try compiling the fortran file, simply deleting the program lines, up to that subroutine definition.  From what I see it looks independant but the compiler will do a better job of checking source code.